# Darüber/darauf etc for plurals?

Tags: pronoun

Can words like "darüber" or "darauf" etc. be used to refer back to a plural noun, or do you have to use constructions like über sie, auf sie etc?

In the case of replacing nouns with pronouns. "Wir haben über die Umwelt, die Kultur und die Landeskunde gelesen" - could we say "Wir haben darüber gelesen" or would this imply there was only one thing that we read about? In other words does "darüber" mean "about that/ it" only, or can it mean "about them". I'm presuming the same rule would apply to any of the other da+preposition words, like darauf, davon etc.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking - can you try and give some example sentences?

Comment: In the case of replacing nouns with pronouns. "Wir haben über die Umwelt, die Kultur und die Landeskunde gelesen" - could we say "Wir haben darüber gelesen" or would this imply there was only one thing that we read about? In other words does "darüber" mean "about that/ it" only, or can it mean "about them". I'm presuming the same rule would apply to any of the other da+preposition words, like darauf, davon etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Darüber**, **darunter**, **darauf**, **daran**, **darin**, **dahinter**, **davor**, **danach** and other *prepositional adverbs* refer back (or forward) to anything. You have to tell solely from context what they refer to, there is no grammatical rule.

> **Worüber** habt ihr gelesen? – Über Umwelt, Kultur und Landeskunde. – Ach, **darüber**.
>
> **Hierüber** sollten Sie sich jetzt schon informieren: Ihre Rente.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if you refer to something in singular or plural:

Singular:

> Frau Hofer hat heute von Gullivers **Reise** nach Brobdingnag erzählt.
>   *<sup>(Reise = singular; the topic is only one travel)</sup>*
>   Aber Herr Gruber hat schon vor einer Woche **darüber** berichtet.

Plural:

> Frau Hofer hat heute von Gullivers **Reisen** erzählt.
>   *<sup>(Reisen = Plural; the topic is all four travels)</sup>*
>   Aber Herr Gruber hat schon vor einer Woche **darüber** berichtet.